# Response architecture

Tags: node.js, httpresponse

I have the following question.

I have an endpoint which returns some data with the following format.

```
[
    {
      avr_video_likes = 15;
      avr_video_likes_ratio = 3;
      avr_video_views = 1500;
      avr_views_ratio = 7.2;
      avr_video_comments = 4;
      avr_video_comments_ratio = 75;
    }
    .....
]
```

the possible values are 0 or positive ones.
So I was wondering, if a value doesnt exist at all in my database which is the the best response to send.

1. Return -1 in order to show that the value doesnt exist. Because values are type of number
2. Return "-"
3. Dont return the value at all.

Which one is the best option and why?
Thank you for your time

Comment: IMHO the best option is returning null for not exsisting values

Comment: @Darth thank your for your answer!